# Microsoft Access VBA - Locking a field when value in the field is not null

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have fallen into a rut building a quote creation tool. I have a combo box that selects an item for the quote and will populate all of the fields for that line. In this case, I want the [Cost] field to be locked, preventing any changes. However, there are times when a user must type an item for the quote that is not in the combo box; therefore, all of the fields on that line will be null and must be typed manually.

I am trying to write a VBA event where [Cost] is locked when [Cost] is not null, preventing any change; and where [Cost] is not locked when [Cost] is Null, allowing editing.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If IsNull(Me.Cost) = True Then
    Me.Cost.Locked = False
Else
    Me.Cost.Locked = True
End If
End Sub
```

[image: Design view of subform]

[image: Form view of complete form]

- The top line is in the combo box and the entire line is populated; **Here I want cost to be locked**
- The second line is not in the combo and the line must be manually entered; **Here I want lock to be disabled**

Comment: What is the question? You have code so what happens - error message, wrong result, nothing? Consider using Conditional Formatting to Enable/Disable textbox or combobox.

Comment: @June7 It currently is locking the entire field, regardless if the line is blank or auto-populated

Comment: Programmatically setting control's properties will affect ALL instances of control. So the property setting in the Current event should apply as user navigates records. It should not be apparent to user. They should be able to edit or not edit as appropriate for record that has focus. Again, consider Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So in other words, there is no way to programmatically set whether the cost on the QuoteID line can be locked or unlocked? The reason I want to set this is for security; I do not want a user to edit the cost field if the line is populated from the combo box. If the desired service item is not in the combo box, they need to have the ability to fill out the entire line. I am quite new to access in general, so I am not sure if there is a better approach to this, or if it is even possible.

Comment: It is locked or unlocked when record gets focus. Sounds like you also need code in combobox event. If Cost is populated by selection in combobox, what code does that? Again, use Conditional Formatting and this will take of disabling textbox as soon as Cost gets populated.

Comment: Is combobox entry restricted to items in list? If item is not in list, does it need to be added to a lookup table? If combobox is not restricted and you want to allow users to enter anything, and therefore allow Cost to be editable for those items, that does complicate things.

Comment: The combobox is of course created from a table with service items that will be used to build a quote, but not restricted. I can type anything I want into the box on the form. Items not in the list do not need to be added anywhere, as they are likely to be unique and not needed again. For those items that are typed in, I do need to allow editing on Cost. .

Comment: So in short, if the item is selected from the combobox, all of the information for that line is good; I just need to lock the Cost field. If the item is not in the combobox, and is typed in, I need to have the ability to edit cost.

Comment: Allow Cost edit if that record is revisited in future? That does complicate. Code or Conditional Formatting rule would likely have to employ DLookup() to determine if item is/is not in lookup table. Most anything can be done with enough code. Sometimes have to think 'outside the box'.

Comment: This is just for data entry into the quote database table. If I ever need to refer revisit, I would simply locate the quote id that is generated, which would include everything that was entered, regardless if it is in a dimension table or not.

Comment: Okay, then seems you have solution. Code in Current and combobox AfterUpdate events.

Comment: That was it, I didn't realize that I had to do an afterupdate on that combo. Thank you!!!

Comment: I did mention that in my third comment. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes code must be in multiple events to achieve desired result. Since you will programmatically populate Cost if an item is selected from combobox list, put code in form Current event and combobox AfterUpdate event. Could have a Sub behind form that can be called by both events.

Programmatically setting control's properties will affect ALL instances of control. An alternative is to use Conditional Formatting to dynamically enable/disable a textbox or combobox.

To allow user option to edit manually entered Cost value for a new record adds complication. VBA or Conditional Formatting rule could be conditional - don't disable if focus is on a new record and service item is not in lookup table.